# Ui-router - how to wait template loading before trigger state entry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ng-include to get my templates:

```
<div ng-include=" ' partials/commonsTemplates.html ' "></div>
```

When I click in a ui-sref it works well (I believe it's because the template is already loaded), but on F5 press I get a 404 error. Is there a way to force the ui-router to wait the file loading before trigger the navigation to it?

Additionally, one template (randomicaly) is ever not loded, even after the file load.

My router config is simple, like:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url:"/home",
      templateUrl:"home.html"
    })
    .state('users', {
      url:"/users",
      templateUrl:"users.html",
      controller:'usersCtrl'
    })
    .state('customer', {
      url:"/customer",
      templateUrl:"customer.html",  
      controller:'customersCtrl'           
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you using to serve the pages? static HTML or something like node.js?

Comment: Static html, RESTFul in PHP

Comment: did you enable HTML5 mode?